# Code in single.php works but not all the time

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is my first time asking a question but I am creating my own theme in Wordpress and everything has been quite good so far. In `singe.php` I want to have a side bar, in which all embedded photos in the post should be displayed. It works, but only on one post. When I switch to a more recent post, the code doesn't do its job, but everything else works.

Here is the code that doesn't work all the time but still does sometimes:

```
<?php
    $images = get_attached_media( 'image' );
    $i = 2;

    if ( $images ) {
        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full' );

            if ( $image_attributes ) {
                ?>
                <div class="sc-image<?php echo ( $i % 3 === 0 ) ? ' new-row' : ''; ?>">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#image-modal-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image_attributes[0] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $image->post_title ); ?>" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is the full single.php content:
https://pastecode.io/s/ai57j211

Does anyone have an idea of why Wordpress doesn't want to make this code work all the time?

I have tried reinstalling WP, create new posts with new images, change code.

Comment: The function you are using [get_attached_media()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/) accepts as second parameter the ID of the post the images belongs to. By default it use the ID of the current post, so, if the post has no image, it returns nothing. You should try another way.